# Finding all permutations of ArrayList<Point> and putting them into new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>

Tags: java, arraylist, permutation

I have some problems with writing a code of method that returns all the permutations of ArrayList.

I have found that algorithm:

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    permuteString("", "String");
  }

  public static void permuteString(String beginningString, String endingString) {
    if (endingString.length() <= 1)
      System.out.println(beginningString + endingString);
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < endingString.length(); i++) {
          String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);
          permuteString(beginningString + endingString.charAt(i), newString);

      }
  }
}
```

Which is working great for strings, but when I am trying to rewrite that for ArrayLists - I am finding some troubles.

Here is code that i have writed:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> listaPermutacji = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();

public static void perm(ArrayList<Point> soFar, ArrayList<Point> rest) {
        if (rest.size() <= 1) {
            ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>();
            temp = soFar;
            for (int i = 0; i < rest.size(); i++) {
                temp.add(rest.get(i));
            }
            listaPermutacji.add(temp);
        } else {
            for (int k = 0; k < rest.size(); k++) {
                ArrayList<Point> remaining = new ArrayList<Point>();
                List<Point> sublist = rest.subList(0, k);
                for (int a = 0; a < sublist.size(); a++) {
                    remaining.add(sublist.get(a));
                }
                sublist.clear();
                if (rest.size() >= k + 1) {
                    sublist = rest.subList(k + 1, rest.size());
                    for (int a = 0; a < sublist.size(); a++) {
                        remaining.add(sublist.get(a));
                    }
                }
                ArrayList<Point> beginning = new ArrayList<Point>();
                beginning = soFar;
                System.out.println("Beginning size= " + beginning.size());
                System.out.println("Rest size= " + rest.size());
                System.out.println("k= " + k);
                if(k<rest.size()){
                    beginning.add(rest.get(k));
                }
                perm(beginning, remaining);
            } 
        } 
    }
```

This is returning, for example for Array of 3 points:

```
x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | 
x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | 
x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 1.0 y= 0.0 | x= 0.0 y= 1.0 | x= 4.0 y= 3.0 |
```

I really cannot understand that... I am trying to fix this for about 4 hours and I'm still getting other problems...

By the way, I need this generator to make a bruteforce method of resolving Traveling Salesman Problem...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are ready to use an external lib, Guava has `Collections2.permutations()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I really don't know how to use this... I am programming in java since 1 or 2 months, so my skills aren't good...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your mistake is there :

```
 ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>();
 temp = soFar;
```

If you want `temp` to be a copy (a new list) you should replace those two lines by `ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>(soFar);`

Comment: I have tried to replace this code, and also replace                `ArrayList<Point> beginning = new ArrayList<Point>();
                beginning = soFar;` and it gives some results, but...

Now I am getting this:
<br/><br/>
``x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | x= 2.0 y= 4.0 | x= 2.0 y= 2.0 | ``<br/>
``x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | x= 2.0 y= 4.0 | ``<br/>
``x= 2.0 y= 2.0 | x= 4.0 y= 3.0 | ``

Comment: Sorry for the style of my comment - I am new here and I need a moment to know how to use Comment formatting... Anyway, that is some progress, but I still don't know what may I change...

Comment: I looked at it at midnight, to be honest I stopped at the first potential bug and didn't check the rest of the code so it may not fix all the problems indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). This problem-solving technique is heavily based on recursion. Basically, you set your first point, then only consider the other points as a sub-problem, and when every permutation has been found with that first point, it is incremented, and so on.

Your solution would be something like what follows. For simplicity, I made it with an array of integers, but you should be able to change the integers to points easily. Think of these integers as the indexes of your points in the Arraylist.

```
public class PermutationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[4];

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            reset(array, i);
        }

        solve(array, 0);
    }

    private static void solve(int[] array, int i) {
        if (i == array.length) {
            print(array);
            return;
        }

        for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
            solve(array, i+1);
            makeMove(array, i);
        }

        reset(array, i);
    }

    private static void makeMove(int[] array, int i) {
        array[i] += 1;
    }

    private static void reset(int[] array, int i) {
        array[i] = 1;
    }

    private static void print(int[] array) {
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
PS [10:21] Desktop > java PermutationDemo
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
1 3 4
1 4 1
1 4 2
1 4 3
1 4 4
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 1 4
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 4 1
2 4 2
2 4 3
2 4 4
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 1 4
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 2 4
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 4 1
3 4 2
3 4 3
3 4 4
4 1 1
4 1 2
4 1 3
4 1 4
4 2 1
4 2 2
4 2 3
4 2 4
4 3 1
4 3 2
4 3 3
4 3 4
4 4 1
4 4 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
```